# How to do variable change for a general Fourier series? I failed at first step :(

Tags: integral-transforms

Well, firtly, I think I should define a general rule for Fourier series, but I fails.

Below is my code including several attempts.

Anys helps are greatly appreciated, thanks.

````
(*try 1*)
(*f/:Integrate[f[t]E^(-I k_ t_),{t_,-Pi,Pi}]:=2Pi \
F[x]/;IntegerQ[k]*)

(*try 2*)
(*f/:Integrate[f[t_]E^(-I k t_),t_]/;IntegerQ[k]:=2Pi F[t]*)

(*try 3*)
rule[x_] := 
 x //. {Integrate[f[t_] E^(-I k t_), {t_, -Pi, Pi}] /; IntegerQ[k] :> 
    2 Pi F[t]}

(*try 4*)
rule[x_] := 
 x //. {Integrate[f[t_] E^(-I k t_), t] /; IntegerQ[k] :> F[t]}

1/(2 Pi) Integrate[f[x] E^(-I k t), {x, -Pi, Pi}, 
   Assumptions -> k \[Element] Integers] // rule
```
````

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: What do you mean by “variable change for a general Fourier series”? Can you elaborate a bit? It's not immediately clear at least for me.

Comment: @xzczd Thank you! I am sorry for my poor english. Given a Fourier series of a function `f[x]`, then I have another variable `y = g[x]` which is a linear transform of `x`. How can Fourier series of `f[g^-1[y]]`.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify this.